# Wrong timing on performance review?

Tags: performance-reviews

**Backstory:**

Within the company, I started working in one department (with Manager A) and was 'promoted' to a different department (with Manager B). Manager A, as part of the performance review, did my review early and also promoted me to that new department. This is my first full year with Manager B but now its been 13 months (company does annual reviews) since my last review. My anniversary is on February.

**Issue:**

I've been holding off asking Manager B for a review since it was the holidays and is always hectic around that time. I was going to ask him this week about it but he just approached me today about a new project. If I ask for a review now, would he think that I thought the project might be too difficult and therefore he would not approach me for new projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't read his mind any more than you can.

But, if a review is due, then ask for it, there is nothing untoward about that, it directly concerns your remuneration which is your primary reason for getting out of bed each day and going to work. A project about to start is no reason to delay.

Comment: Yeah, understood. It was more about the conversation that ensues during the review because of the timing. I want to make sure the focus is on the work I've already done rather than the new task that hasn't started yet. Another issue I forgot to mention was that this manager is newer than I am and might not be aware of when the previous review took place.

Answer (score 0):

A side note: Performance reviews are often written into you contract and not organising one when it's due is really a breach of the foundation that your relationship with the company stands on.

You should definitely ask for the review. It is **not** OK for a company to skip performance reviews.

There is a psychological aspect to your situation as well - you not asking for a review when it is due can easily be seen as being in a weak position when it comes to salary negotiation.

Finally, this is all in a context, if you are satisfied with your conditions then it may be OK to skip a review.